# The find Command with -exec Does Not Run the -exec Command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, exec, rm

I want to write a simple command to cleanup my project files, so I used:

```
find . -type f -name "*.o" -o -name "*.a" -o -name "*.ko" -exec rm '{}' +
```

Oddly it didn't work. And when I removed " -exec rm '{}' +" I could see that it dumped the files out the terminal, so it looks like my expression is correct. I even tried changing "'{}' +" to "'{}' \;", but this also didn't work. I also tried replacing rm with echo but nothing was displayed in the terminal. Am I doing something wrong?

Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.o" -o -name "*.a" -o -name "*.ko" \) -exec rm -f {} \;
```

When using multiple files with `find` combined with `exec` it often only acts on the last filename.

Comment: Wording here is a bit confusing. The need for the grouping doesn't really have much to do with `-exec` and more to with the precedence `find` gives its options. Namely most options have equal precedence until `-or`'s are introduced, which have a lower presence. So `find` would treat the original syntax as `(-type f AND -name "*.o") OR (-name "*.a") OR (-name "*.ko" AND -exec rm '{}' +)`

Comment: Also the `+` is better than `\;` since `rm` can take a series of filenames as arguments, so `find` won't have to spawn a new subshell for each `-exec` and will run faster.